# How to know if a mat-option is selected or not from a click event?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multiple `mat-select` and would like to know if the `mat-option` that's been clicked has been selected or deselected. The `$event.target` object passed when the `(click)` is fired has no `selected` attribute I could use.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="control" multiple>
        <mat-option 
          *ngFor="let option of options" 
          [value]="option"
          (click)="foo($event)"
        >
        {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
public foo(event) {
    const hasBeenChecked = ???? // How do I know if my clicked option has been checked or unchecked?
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the selected state of the clicked option by reading it off of the [MatOption](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/option/option.ts#L98) object as follows:

```
<mat-option #matOption (click)="foo(matOption.selected)"></mat-option>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a31hr6)

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate that matOption.selected attribute from javascript (or typescript)?

Answer (score 5):

Using Angular 11.0 worked to add in the mat-option tag the (click) event see below:

```
<mat-option (click)="handleSelected(option)" *ngFor="let option of   filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
```

And you get the displayed value

Answer (score 3):

You can use `selectionChange()` event on `<mat-select>` which will give you the option you selected.

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="foo($event)">
```

The best practice would be to get the change straight from FormControl. If you `console.log` the FormControl you use: `[formControl]="control"`, you will see that it holds the last selected option. If you have multiple mat-selects, and would like to have them in control, my suggestion is to wrap them in a `FormGroup` and then use `FormControl` which belongs to that `FormGroup` for each of the selects.

Answer (score -1):

You are already using a formcontrol. All your selected options are there, stored in an array:

```ts
foo(x) {
  // an array of your selections
  console.log(this.control.value)
}
```

So you don't need to track if it's unchecked or checked.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-trqbx2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**