# How to enable input fields if a certain mat-option is selected or not?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-form-field, mat-option

Based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496789/how-to-know-if-a-mat-option-is-selected-or-not-from-a-click-event)'s accepted answer, I managed to get the selected state of the clicked option. I want to disable an input based on a selection of a certain option. With the below example, I am able to enable/disable the input when any option is checked/unchecked. For example, I want to disable the input field only if the second option (Mushroom) is unchecked. If the second option is checked, the input field could be enabled. How could I do it?

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a31hr6-8kmbbg?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.html,app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Comment: are you using angular forms to preserve data?

Comment: All my `mat-form-field` are in `<form class="example-form" #connectDBForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveConnDB(connectDBForm.value)">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496789/how-to-know-if-a-mat-option-is-selected-or-not-from-a-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by attaching your formcontrol value to mat-input's [disabled] directive.

1)just read toppings(form control) value

```
isValueSelected(): boolean {
    var valueArray: any = this.toppings.value || [];
    console.log(valueArray, valueArray.includes('Mushroom'));
    return !valueArray.includes('Mushroom');
 }
```

2)attach it to [disabled] directive

```
<input id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" name="numeDB_SQLite" [disabled]="isValueSelected()"/>
```

i have updated your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a31hr6-fxgfy2?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts). please upvote/select if helps.

Answer (score 0):

If want disabled if some value is selected

```
<input id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput 
      [disabled]="toppings?.value && toppings.value.length" ../>
```

If want disabled when one element is selected, e.g.

```
<input id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput 
          [disabled]="toppings?.value && toppings.value.includes('Mushroom')" ../>
```